# Slicing with a logical (boolean) expression a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, slice, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I am getting an exception as I try to slice with a logical expression my Pandas dataframe.

My data have the following form:

```
df
    GDP_norm    SP500_Index_deflated_norm
Year        
1980    2.121190    0.769400
1981    2.176224    0.843933
1982    2.134638    0.700833
1983    2.233525    0.829402
1984    2.395658    0.923654
1985    2.497204    0.922986
1986    2.584896    1.09770

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 38 entries, 1980 to 2017
Data columns (total 2 columns):
GDP_norm                     38 non-null float64
SP500_Index_deflated_norm    38 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 912.0 bytes
```

The command is the following:

```
df[((df['GDP_norm'] >=3.5 & df['GDP_norm'] <= 4.5) & (df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] > 3)) | (

   (df['GDP_norm'] >= 4.0 & df['GDP_norm'] <= 5.0) & (df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] < 3.5))]
```

The error message is the following:

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest create boolean masks separately for better readibility and also easier error handling.

Here are missing `()` in `m1` and `m2` code, problem is in operator precedence:

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#arithmetic-conversions) - 6.16. Operator precedence where see `&` have higher priority as `>=`:

```
Operator                                Description

lambda                                  Lambda expression
if – else                               Conditional expression
or                                      Boolean OR
and                                     Boolean AND
not x                                   Boolean NOT
in, not in, is, is not,                 Comparisons, including membership tests    
<, <=, >, >=, !=, ==                    and identity tests
|                                       Bitwise OR
^                                       Bitwise XOR
&                                       Bitwise AND

(expressions...), [expressions...],     Binding or tuple display, list display,       
{key: value...}, {expressions...}       dictionary display, set display
```

---

```
m1 = (df['GDP_norm'] >=3.5) & (df['GDP_norm'] <= 4.5)
m2 = (df['GDP_norm'] >= 4.0) & (df['GDP_norm'] <= 5.0)

m3 = m1 & (df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] > 3)
m4 = m2 & (df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] < 3.5)

df[m3 | m4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are suffering from the effects of [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). What's happening is the expression `df['GDP_norm'] >=3.5 & df['GDP_norm'] <= 4.5` is evaluated as something like:

```
df['GDP_norm'] >= (3.5 & df['GDP_norm']) <= 4.5
```

Of course, this fails since `float` cannot be compared with `bool`, as described in your error message. Instead, use parentheses to isolate each Boolean mask and assign to variables:

```
m1 = (df['GDP_norm'] >= 3.5) & (df['GDP_norm'] <= 4.5)
m2 = df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] > 3

m3 = (df['GDP_norm'] >= 4.0) & (df['GDP_norm'] <= 5.0)
m4 = df['SP500_Index_deflated_norm'] < 3.5

res = df[(m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4)]
```